# Copying Range from one workbook to another

Tags: copy-paste

I wrote a code the other day that worked fine up till now. However, it appears that it is not running anymore for unkown reasons.

Basically, I am copying a range from workbook called `Data.xlsm` (several tabs) to `Masterfile.xlsm` (on first tab).

Code looks as follows:

```
Sub CopyingRange()

' Set dimensions
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

' Set Workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Data.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\Masterfile.xlsm")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Andorra").Range("L123:O123").Copy Range("T3")
Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Angola").Range("L123:O123").Copy Range("T4")
Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Austria").Range("L123:O123").Copy Range("T5")
Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Bahrain").Range("L123:O123").Copy Range("T6")
Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Belgium").Range("L123:O123").Copy Range("T7")
Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Botswana").Range("L123:O123").Copy Range("T8")

End Sub
```

Comment: are you receiving an error message? are either of the Excel file open by yourself or another user?

Comment: The issue is that it works from time to time. Either I get "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range" because Data.xlsm is somehow not visible within VBA Project or it just does not work (without error message). Please note that both files (Data.xlsm and Masterfile.xlsm) are open. The code is written withing Masterfile.xlsm, Module 1. Hope this explaiins the situation better. Not sure how to include Data.xlsm into VBA project.